# Output of Remote GDB Debugger in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, gdb, cross-platform

Is it possible to have access to stdout of remote GDB session in Visual Studio? I am using Visual Studio Visual C++ for Linux Development and would like to have access to all printf'd data.

Comment: I am aware only about this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/11/18/announcing-the-vs-gdb-debugger-extension/

Answer (score 2):

IMHO both stdout and stderr should be passed to an Output or Debug window by the ssh/gdb pipe of MSVC but they aren't, at least in MSVC 2017, version 15.3. Hopefully Microsoft will implement this for us later.

In the meantime, a workaround can be used in gdbserver mode. Debuggee's stdout ends up somewhere in the ssh virtual terminal. It can be redirected, e.g. to `/tmp/stdout` by setting Debug/solution Properties/Debugging/Program Arguments to `>/tmp/stdout`, which can be watched in another terminal by `tail -f /tmp/stdout`.

Another way to see stdout is to show it in a separate window when the debugger starts, much like a new console in Win32 Console process shows up. This can be achieved through X server running on the same machine as MSVC. E.g. Xming works fine on Windows 7 (note that the remote Linux machine must be allowed in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Xming\X0.hosts`). X's `DISPLAY` environment variable on the remote Linux machine must be set to the debugging Windows machine's display, e.g. to `192.168.1.10:0`. Set Debug/solution Properties/Debugging/Pre-Launch Command to `export DISPLAY=192.168.1.10:0` (replace the IP address by your Windows' machine one) or let shell to fill the IP for you by `` export DISPLAY="`sed -e 's/ .*/:0/'<<<"$SSH_CLIENT"`" ``. This time pipe stdout by setting Debug/solution Properties/Debugging/Program Arguments to `|xless -f` (xless must be installed on the remote Linux machine, e.g. by `apt-get install xless`).

Note that stdout is not always flushed by the debuggee with a new line when redirected, so `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)` as the first call in `main()` will help.

It also looks like stderr is eaten by MSVC debugging pipe, so it cannot be redirected without debugging failure, but `stderr=stdout` in `main()` will help.